# Need Google Map InfoWindow Hyperlink to Open Content in Overlay (Fusion Table Usage)

Tags: jquery, google-maps, fancybox, google-fusion-tables, fancybox-2

I have the following code established to render the map in my site. When the map is clicked in any region, an info window pops up with some content including a hyperlink to open up a website with a form in it. I would like to utilize fancybox to open up this link "form" in an overlay. I have been unsuccessful getting Fancybox to work (version 1.3.4), and have read that it doesn't support calling the function from within an iframe. I was wondering if this was the issue, and if there was another way to utilize fancybox (or another overlay option)? Maybe an event listener or callback - any tips would be much appreciated!

```
<style>
    #map-canvas { width:850px; height:600px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

<script src="http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/src/fusiontips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
        var tableid = "1nDFsxuYxr54viD_fuH7fGm1QRZRdcxFKbSwwRjk";
    var layer;
    var initialLocation;
    var browserSupportFlag =  new Boolean();
    var uscenter = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6970, -91.8096);

    function initialize() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            zoom: 4,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
            query: {
                select: "'Geometry'",
                from: tableid
            },
            map: map
        });

                //http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/reference.html
                layer.enableMapTips({
                    select: "'Contact Name','Contact Title','Contact Location','Contact Phone'", 
                    from: tableid,
                    geometryColumn: 'Geometry',
                    suppressMapTips: false,
                    delay: 500,
                    tolerance: 8
                });
            ;
        // Try W3C Geolocation (Preferred) 
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            browserSupportFlag = true;
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(initialLocation);

                                //Custom Marker
                                var pinColor = "A83C0A";
                    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
                        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
                        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
                                var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
                        new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
                        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                        new google.maps.Point(12, 35));

                new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: initialLocation,
                    map: map,
                                        icon: pinImage,
                                        shadow: pinShadow
                });
            }, function() {
                handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
            });
        }
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        else {
            browserSupportFlag = false;
            handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
        }

        function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
            if (errorFlag == true) {
                //Geolocation service failed
                initialLocation = uscenter;
            } else {
                //Browser doesn't support geolocation
                initialLocation = uscenter;
            }
            map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        } 
    }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

RESOLVED by upgrading to Fancybox Version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your [demo site](https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/?previewAuth=1kgEiTlvE4rLDhjw7T4IuzA_DM1XVQ0hA67fExiaFsCyLQKnyabcFnTr.0HmpBZlZ4MDmiA%3D%3DA) I think you need to fix some issues.

**First**, this code should work for your scenario

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.form-modal").fancybox({
 // I would suggested to set some dimensions to the iframe (try without them first if you want)
    width: 640, // or whatever
    height: 320, 
    type : "iframe"
  });
}); // ready
```

*Notice* that I am disregarding the use of `.on()` as suggested by *Dr.Molle* since it seems that you are using Fancybox v2.x, which uses the `live` method.

**Second** : link the proper Fancybox's CSS stylesheet according to the version you are using... currently you are linking to a [fancybox v1.3.4](https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css?v=38&SiteID=0DMd0000000PLRT) CSS stylesheet when you are using fancybox v2.1.3

**Third** : Use a single instance of jQuery (ideally the latest version). Currently you are loading two, [v1.5.2](https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/sfsites/assets/Scripts/jquery/jquery.js?r=1.201210231947310162) and [v1.7](https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/jquery-1.7.js?v=1&r=1.201210231947310162)

... also  make sure that jQuery is loaded before any other js plugin so you will avoid this type of js errors

```
Timestamp: 26/10/2012 11:54:49 AM
Error: TypeError: jQuery("ul.sf-menu").superfish is not a function
Source File: https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/contact-us
Line: 756
```

Comment: Had this code originally (well, similar) and didn't work with previous version of Fancybox. Of course, I didn't update the stylesheet along with that, so my error and that fixed it! Tried my original code with everything all updated and worked like a charm - you're a lifesaver. Updating Fancybox (all components LOL) was the ultimate resolution - glad that the update was available for what I needed to do. Thanks for all your valuable time and help - was very simple in the end, as usual LOL :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me(using fancybox2 )

```
jQuery(function($){
 $('#map-canvas')
  .on('click',
      'a.video-modal',
      function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).data('fancybox-type','iframe');
        $.fancybox(this);
     });
  });
```

All the Links have the same class(video-modal), so you only have to :

1. observe the click on these links and when it happens:
2. set the `data-fancybox-type` of the link to 'iframe'
3. open the fancybox by supplying the link-object as argument

Comment: Okay, so I tried that and am getting some action now, which is awesome! However, I just get the black button in the center of the page which indicates it's loading...but never does load the overlay...no errors. I do have another call on the page to fancybox on a separate element, but I'm not sure if that would really cause any issues.

Comment: Okay, so looking better now...determined I had an older version of Fancybox. Updated that and get a really crappy pseudo overlay looking thing...determining what's going on there now.

Comment: For simplicity, you could get rid of this line `$(this).data('fancybox-type','iframe');` and do this instead `$.fancybox(this,{type:"iframe"});`.

Comment: @McKev : those suggested changes are based on Dr.Molle's script above

Comment: @JFK Looks good - issue is the overlay sort of comes up to the right (initially) and then seems to embed itself into the page above the map. Is this because I haven't specified any other fancybox attributes yet?

Comment: @McKev does Dr.Molle's script with no modifications do the same?

Comment: @JFK Yes. Here is what I have thus far (FYI - changed video-modal to form-modal):  jQuery(function($){
   $('#map-canvas')
    .on('click',
        'a.form-modal',
        function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          $.fancybox(this,{type:"iframe"});
       });
   });

Comment: @McKev I guess that is another issue. You accepted Dr.Molle's answer so I assumed everything was fine ... I just tried to improve his answer. It would be better if you provide a link to see the NEW issue.

Comment: @JFK I've unaccepted - originally just thought it was not having other attributes specified. Click here and then on "Contact Us" to the right tab. https://sitepreview.na14.force.com/?previewAuth=1kgEiTlvE4rLDhjw7T4IuzA_DM1XVQ0hA67fExiaFsCyLQKnyabcFnTr.0HmpBZlZ4MDmiA%3D%3DA